# laravel-localization give me error when run server

Tags: laravel, localization

when I run server It is currently giving me this error

```
Trait 'Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LocalizationTrait' not found but I solve it by written 
use App\Http\Controllers\Traits\LocalizationTrait; in LaravelLocalization.php file
```

but this caused another problem :
server is working but if open brwser router is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/countries" and the page not working and display error msg:

```
[Tue Oct  6 11:46:24 2020] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization::exceptRedirectionPath() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\packages\mcamara\laravel-localization\src\Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization.php:273
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(261): Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization->getLocalizedURL('de', NULL, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\app\Helpers\Functions\core.php(398): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('getLocalizedURL', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\storage\framework\views\3d0f194ac9896b9a0f4a0976c680d46f6dc16cc6.php(224): lurl(NULL, Array, 'de')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php(41): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine.php(57): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#5 C in C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\packages\mcamara\laravel-localization\src\Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization.php on line 273
[Tue Oct  6 11:46:24 2020] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization::exceptRedirectionPath() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\packages\mcamara\laravel-localization\src\Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization.php:273
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(261): Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization->getLocalizedURL('de', NULL, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\app\Helpers\Functions\core.php(398): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('getLocalizedURL', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\storage\framework\views\3d0f194ac9896b9a0f4a0976c680d46f6dc16cc6.php(224): lurl(NULL, Array, 'de')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine.php(41): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine.php(57): Illuminate\View\Engines\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#5 C in C:\xampp\htdocs\shobbeek\packages\mcamara\laravel-localization\src\Larapen\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalization.php on line 273
```

Comment: try composer update

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer, it was helped me.
It talked about importing the facade at your `route.php` file

```
<PHP

use \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Facades\LaravelLocalization;

... the rest of the code ...
```

Hope it helps you:
https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/issues/485#issuecomment-327246445